# where is saved localStorage of an app's webview on the phone fileSystem?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview, local-storage

I published a phonegap/webview application on the Play Store.
Now, that the app has some problems,
I need to access localStorage data to recover them, but I can't.

I can't because it's no more "debuggable", it's signed.

Wondering if I can access to those data through filesystem, mounting it via usb cable.

I guess under
    /data/data/package_name (on a rooted phone)
I can find it.

Please share your experience if any.

Comment: i think your problem is not the localStorrage that you can access with a javascript based app. if you want to access the phones filesystem you have to use a cordova-plugin for that because the browser storrage can not access this.

Comment: @mtizziani I don't want to access to the filesystem through the app, I wanted to access to localStorage (html5 url sensitive string based storage) through usb cable... mounting the filesystem and finding the files it was saved in - I cannot understand why downvoting without any info.

Comment: it is not possible to access the browsers localStorage from outside the box.

Comment: Do you have any source about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cordova file plugin to delete and read files and directories. Complete docs is available : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

In Android you can get the data from any file manager app: InternalStorage/data//files/

Comment: I dont need to do it FROM INSIDE the application.

Comment: you have to root the mobile to access the full filesystem of android after that you can access to any file inside file system